# export dropdown array from angular material table to csv

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am looking for an example where I can export angular material values to excel.

I have tried to use the XLSX library but it is not copying the whole dropdown list and converting dropdown data set in excel (instead it is just copying selected value).

Kindly help here.

Below is my stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-export-excel-xlsx-i4hpvr